# Add new column with column names of a table, based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas table in Python

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Jim', 1, 1, 1, 0], ['Jack', 1, 0, 0, 1], ['Joe', 0, 1, 1, 1]]),
                   columns=['name', 'slot1', 'slot2', 'slot3', 'slot4'])
```

And I want to add a new column which contains the names of the columns when the value in each column is 0.

The desired outcome should be the following.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['Jim', 1, 1, 1, 0, 'slot4'], ['Jack', 1, 0, 0, 1, 'slot2,slot3'], ['Joe', 0, 1, 1, 1, 'slot1']]),
                   columns=['name', 'slot1', 'slot2', 'slot3', 'slot4', 'error'])
```

I tried the following codes but they don't give the desired outcome:

```
df1['error'] = df1.loc[:,"slot1":"slot4"].apply(lambda row: row[row == 0].index, axis=1)

df1['error'] = df1.loc[:,"slot1":"slot4"].isin(["0"]).idxmax(1)
```

Could you please suggest a solution on this task?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: IIUC `df1.mask(df1.ne('0')).stack().reset_index(1).groupby(level=0)['level_1'].agg(','.join)` quite a few ways to do this and has been asnwered before let me find a dupe also `df1.eq('0').dot(df1.columns + ';').str.rstrip(';')`

Comment: @Manakin your answer was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: no problemo, thanks for the well formatted question!